# Compiling hadoop source in windows

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, ant

I want to compile the hadoop source. But I searched the web but most of them were built using maven in eclipse... But I want to build it using ant, eclipse and in windows.

Can any one share their knowledge about how to compile hadoop source file in eclipse using ant (not maven) in windows

Comment: If it is built with maven you will find it much easier to stick with using maven

Comment: yes..but my requirement is to build with ant

Comment: Two very important bits of advice: 1. Use the right tool for the job 2. Never use windows

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows. You will need to do a fair amount of work to reproduce what Maven provides for you. I think you're asking for a *world* of hurt, and without understanding *why* you'd want to do this, it seems ridiculous.